# Formato de un email en PYTHON

Tags: python, email, formato, count

[image: Este es el problema que debia resolver...]

```
    n=int(input('Ingrese tamaño de la lista:  '))
v=[None]*n
for i in range (n):
    v[i]=str(input('Ingrese e-mail: '))
cp=0
cd=0
ca=0
bana=0
band=0
pun=0
for i in range(0,n,1):
    ca=v[i].count(''@'')
    if ca>1:
        bana=1
while v[i]!=''@'':
    cd=cd+1
    i=i+1
    if cd>5:
        band=1
if (bana==0) and (band==1):
    i=0
    ar=0
    a=str(''@'')
    for i in range(n):
        ar=v[i].find(a)
        if (v[i][ar+1]=='.'):
            pun=pun+1   
        if v[n]=='.':
                pun=pun+1
```

Ese fue el razonamiento que tuve, intentando buscar la cantidad de @, pero a la hora de contar la funcion 'count()' me tomaba como invalido el '@'. El resto no puedo saber si esta bien por el problema de base con el que empece.. si a alguien se le ocurre alguna idea un poco mas simple, espero me la puedan hacer saber.

Comment: Creo que esto `''@''` debe de dar error de sintaxis

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'str' and 'str'`
ese es el mensaje que me da de error

Comment: Obviamente por que esa sintaxis esta  mal, debe de ser `'@'`

Comment: Probleema solucionado, pero ahora me dice que en linea 15: `while v[i]!='@':` esta fuera de rango

Comment: Hola Martin, efectivamente tu error pasa por que la sintaxis esta mal, debe ser solo con 1 `@`. pero te recomendaría evitar tantos bucles para realizar validaciones. Toma en cuenta que puedes realizar todo eso solo en 1 `for` evaluando un texto que contiene el correo. para varias de tus validaciones puedes usar `split`, `count` y `len`

Comment: `if '@' in email:`

Comment: @arce.est muchas gracias por el collab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo ideal es crear una función que se encargue de validar cada email, primero tendremos que hacer la validación de que tenga el `@`, si no lo tiene retornamos el email y la letra `i`, de lo contrario seguimos. Luego usamos `split` para obtener las 2 partes del email, la primera que corresponde al nombre del email y la otra al dominio. Luego solo nos queda validar la posición del punto `.` verificando que no esté luego del `@` y que no esté al final.

```py
def validar(mail):
    mal = [mail,"i"]
    bien= [mail,"c"]
    if mail.count("@")!=1: return mal 
    name,dom=mail.split('@')
    if len(name)>=5 and ("." in dom):
        dom = f"@{dom}"
        if dom.index(".") in (len(dom), 1): return mal
        return bien 
    else: return mal
```

Y lo usamos así:

```py
n=int(input('Ingrese tamaño de la lista:  '))
v=[None]*n

for i in range (n):
    v[i]=validar(input('Ingrese e-mail: '))
```

Siempre es bueno evitar los ciclos e iteraciones de más, por eso opte por una función que recibe email por email

Comment: Christian, me pareció excelente tu forma de explicar, un solo detalle. al realizar el split directo no estas validando que pueda tener más de 1 '@'.

Comment: Listo, lo he corregido

Comment: muchisimas gracias @Christian, super clara la explicacion y despeja todas mis dudas. Ahora lo voy a practicar con esas funciones que usaste vos, abrazo y buen fin de semana!

Answer (score 0):

Esta función valida un email según las reglas:

```
def validar(email):
    try:
        nota = "C"
        nombre, dominio = email.split('@')
        try:
            dom1, dom2 = dominio.split('.',maxsplit = 1)
            if not (len(nombre) >= 5 and dom1 and dom2):
                nota = "I"
        except ValueError:
            # Dominio no contiene "."
            nota = "I"
    except ValueError:
        # email no contiene "@"
        nota = "I"

    return nota
```

La lógica es actuar como si el email fuera correcto para dividirlo en sus partes. Si esto falla, lo atrapamos con `except` y terminamos el proceso.

Partimos asignamos el resultado `nota = "C"`, en la lógica de que el email está bien.

Luego hacemos `split('@')`, con lo cual separamos el nombre y el dominio, validando que el email efectivamente tenga un `@`. Si el `split` falla, se genera una excepción `ValueError`:

```
def validar(email):
    try:
        nota = "C"
        nombre, dominio = email.split('@')
```

Si el email pasa la prueba, intento dividir el dominio nuevamente con `split('.', maxsplit=1)`. Debo obtener dos partes no vacias exactamente si se cumple la condición de que venga al menos un "." en medio.

Si la división funciona, solo que revisar el largo mínimo del nombre y que ambas partes del dominio no estén vacias.

```
    try:
        dom1, dom2 = dominio.split('.',maxsplit = 1)
        if not (len(nombre) >= 5 and dom1 and dom2):
            nota = "I"
    except ValueError:
        # Dominio no contiene "."
        nota = "I"
```

Finalmente se retorna la nota.

#### Demo

```
def validar(email):
    try:
        nota = "C"
        nombre, dominio = email.split('@')
        try:
            dom1, dom2 = dominio.split('.',maxsplit = 1)
            if not (len(nombre) >= 5 and dom1 and dom2):
                nota = "I"
        except ValueError:
            # Dominio no contiene "."
            nota = "I"
    except ValueError:
        # email no contiene "@"
        nota = "I"

    return nota

tests = [
    "",
    "abcef",
    "abcef@",
    "abcef@com",
    "abcef@.com",
    "abcef@com.",
    "abcef@pol.com",
    "abcef.jj@ab.pol.com",
]

for email in tests:
    print(email, validar(email))
```

produce:

```
 I
abcef I
abcef@ I
abcef@com I
abcef@.com I
abcef@com. I
abcef@pol.com C
abcef.jj@ab.pol.com C
```